# redux and listening to scroll events

Tags: redux, rxjs, react-redux, redux-saga

Building a performance sensitive Redux app that needs to listen to scroll/mouse events throughout a user session.

Plain english implementation would be:

"When component A is in the user's viewport, dispatch FOO action"

From my understanding, the function calculateViewPort + the comparison checking would need to be conducted in the store on every scroll event.

This seems excessive and slow (haven't tested it yet).

Is there another implementation or approach that I have not yet considered?

I was thinking about using something like RxJS for Redux, but want to consider the tradeoff between bringing in a new library for performance and solving it with my existing toolkit.

If there's a saga approach, I'm more open to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`InfiniteScroll`](https://github.com/RealScout/redux-infinite-scroll) component. You can refer this and implement in your way or you can use as it is.

Note: this component is not using the `redux-saga`.

It's better to go with `redux-saga` as you would take only the response which comes from the latest api call (last mouse scroll) with [`takeLatest`](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js#L155) effect.

Answer (score 0):

[React Visibility Sensor](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor) might be a good choice here. You can wrap the components in VisibilitySensor component and dispatch an action whenever it is on window viewport.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor'

import CUSTOM_ACTION from 'your-actions'

const CustomComponent = (noticeMe, ...children) => {
      const handleChange = (isVisible) => { if (isVisible) { noticeMe(); } }
      return <VisibilitySensor>{children}</VisibilitySensor>
    }
export connect({}, {
   noticeMe: () => dispatch(CUSTOM_ACTION)
})(CustomComponent)
```